# Difference between a function and its restriction (in $ L_p$)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f \in L_p ( \mu)$ where $\mu$ is some finite measure and $p \geqslant 1$.
Why is it the case that $\forall \varepsilon > 0$, $\exists M, B > 0$ such that
$$\int | f ( x) - g ( x) |^p \mu ( \mathrm{d} x) < \varepsilon,$$ where we have defined $g$ to be $$g ( x) =
[ f ( x) \wedge M] 1 \{ - B \leqslant x \leqslant B \}.$$

$a\wedge b$ stands for the minimum of either $a$ or $b$ and $1\{A\}$ is an indicator function that equals $1$ if condition $A$ holds and $0$ otherwise.

I think that we could argue that this could be done because we could find $B$
such that $\int_B^{\infty} | f ( x) |^p \mu ( \mathrm{d} x)$ would be as small as
possible and we could find $M$ such that $\int_{\{ x : f ( x) > M \}} | f ( x)
|^p \mu ( \mathrm{d} x)$ would be as small as possible, but I don't know how to make this precise.

Comment: What do you mean by $f(x) \wedge M$?

Comment: the minimum of $f(x)$ and $M$.

Comment: And $1\{-B \le x \le B\}$ is the indicator function?

Comment: Yes${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Idea: $A\mapsto\int_A|f|d\mu$ is a measure.

Comment: Brilliant hint!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start from the inequality 
$$\tag{1}|f(x)-[f(x)\wedge M]\chi_{[-B,B]}(x)|\leqslant |f(x)\chi_{\mathbb R\setminus [-B,B]}(x)|+|f(x)-[f(x)\wedge M]|.$$
Since $|f(x)-[f(x)\wedge M]|=0$ if $f(x)\leqslant M$, we obtain $$\tag{2}]|f(x)-[f(x)\wedge M]|=[f(x)-M]\chi_{f^{-1}(M,\infty)}(x)\leqslant |f(x)|\chi_{f^{-1}(M,\infty)}(x).$$
Combining (1) and (2), we obtain 
$$|f(x)-[f(x)\wedge M]\chi_{[-B,B]}(x)|^p\leqslant |f(x)|^p\left(\chi_{\mathbb R\setminus [-B,B]}(x))+\chi_{f^{-1}(M,\infty)}(x)\right).$$
And now we can use the idea mentioned in the OP.

Comment: So, what remains to be done from the start of the solution here is what @Martín-Blas Pérez Pinilla suggested? Take decreasing sets $A_n=\mathbb R\setminus[-n,n]$ and $B_n=\mathbb R\setminus[n,\infty]$, use the continutity of measures to show that the measures over these sets go to zero?